# Foreach ou for por item de nota fiscal

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer um foreach por item no meu código só que não estou conseguindo realizar.

Ex.: tenho uma nota que tem 2 itens, e preciso ler as informações da nota por item, leio o item 01 e depois leio o item 02, só que não estou conseguindo implementar isso no meu código abaixo.

Segue meu código.

```
private void btn_laudo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ItemNota = @"SELECT 
                    SD.D2_COD, 
                    SD.D2_LOTECTL, 
                    QR.QER_REVI, 
                    SD.D2_ITEM 
                  FROM SD2020 AS SD 
                  INNER JOIN QER020 AS QR WITH(NOLOCK) ON QR.QER_LOTE = SD.D2_LOTECTL 
                  WHERE SD.D2_DOC = '" + txt_nota.Text + "' AND SD.D2_ITEM = '" + txt_item.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(ItemNota, conex);
    conex.Open();
    SqlDataReader ler = comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (ler.Read() == true)
    {
        txt_lote.Text = ler[1].ToString();
        txt_codprod.Text = ler[0].ToString();
        txt_revi.Text = ler[2].ToString();
    }
    conex.Close();

    this.CabeçalhoLaudoTableAdapter.Fill_CabLaudo(this.DSLaudosPS.CabeçalhoLaudo, txt_nota.Text, txt_item.Text);
    this.CorpoLaudoTableAdapter.Fill_CorpoLaudo(this.DSLaudosPS.CorpoLaudo, txt_codprod.Text, txt_lote.Text, txt_revi.Text);
    this.rpw_laudo.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: E qual é a dificuldade, jovem?

Comment: E qual o problema? O que tentou fazer com o `foreach`?

Comment: então preciso fazer um foreach pra ler por item de nota fiscal e não estou sabendo fazer este foreach, preciso ler o item 01 produto x e preencher os textbox que passo dentro do reportview que esta no código, ai depois leio p item 02  produto y e passo as informações para o textbox dentro o reportviwer abaixo . Não sei se estou conseguindo explicar minha necessidade.

Comment: Se perceber no minha query acima eu preencho manualmente o numero da nota e o numero do item ai abaixo eu eu leio e preencho os textbox dentro do datareader, ai passo todos os parametros preenchido para dentro dos  textbox no reportviwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova a chave do item da query, e faça o loop no `DataReader`. O Processamento que você precisa fazer na linha, faça dentro do loop.

```
string ItemNota = @"SELECT 
                    SD.D2_COD, 
                    SD.D2_LOTECTL, 
                    QR.QER_REVI, 
                    SD.D2_ITEM 
                  FROM SD2020 AS SD 
                  INNER JOIN QER020 AS QR WITH(NOLOCK) ON QR.QER_LOTE = SD.D2_LOTECTL 
                  WHERE SD.D2_DOC = '" + txt_nota.Text + "';";

    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(ItemNota, conex);
    conex.Open();
    SqlDataReader ler = comando.ExecuteReader();

    while (ler.Read())
    {
          //faça o que precisa com cada linha aqui
        this.CabeçalhoLaudoTableAdapter.Fill_CabLaudo(this.DSLaudosPS.CabeçalhoLaudo, txt_nota.Text, txt_item.Text);
        this.CorpoLaudoTableAdapter.Fill_CorpoLaudo(this.DSLaudosPS.CorpoLaudo, ler[0].ToString(),ler[1].ToString(), ler[2].ToString());
        this.rpw_laudo.RefreshReport();
    }
    ler.Close();
    conex.Close();
```

Comment: Obrigado Rovann, mas o que estou preenchendo nos textbox, eu to jogando pra dentro do reportview abaixo no código.

Comment: acredito que nem seja necessário jogar pra textbox... joga direto pro reportview

Comment: Rovann obrigado pela ajuda, mas ainda esta faltando algum detalhe, porque e o seguinte, na nota que estou digitando tem dois itens, 01 e 02, quando eu rodo o codigo, ele le as informações dos dosi itens mas na tela do reportviwer só mostra na tela o item 02, não mostra o item 01, tinha que mostrar item 01 uma pagina e item 02 outra pagina.

Comment: Acredito que aí seja algo com o reportviewer, nesse caso, não trabalho com ele e não saberia te ajudar. Como a pergunta só fala sobre o loop nos itens, creio que possa ser finalizada.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rovann...ajudou muito mesmo.